# what's the difference: cut vs cut through

Tags: meaning

> butcher's keen knife cut through the meat.
>
> butcher's keen knife cut the meat.

what's the differences of two sentences ? (cut vs cut through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The** butcher's keen knife cut through the meat.
>   **The** butcher's keen knife cut the meat.

They basically mean the same thing.

How does adding "through" change the sentence? It makes the action seem more thorough, complete, and drastic. "All the way *through* the meat". From end-to-end.

Only "cut" could be a small cut, a large cut, any type of cut. It's generic.

Grammatically, they are different. The first sentence has a prepositional phrase (through the meat), while the second sentence has a direct object (meat).